# How to use <b> tag and <a> tag together in HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags, href

I've following text in my webpage:

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.in">Search Engine</a>
```

I want this hyper text tobe in bold. At the same time this hyperlink should work. How to use `<b>` tag with `<a>` tag? Also I don't want to use CSS for making the text bold. I want to use only `<b>` tag for making the hyperlink text bold.

Comment: I prefer to use style->font-wight instead of <b> tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

Your link is inside a `body` tag so what's wrong with `b` tag ? :-)

`<b><a href="http://www.google.co.in">Search Engine</a></b>`

Also

`<a href="http://www.google.co.in"><b>Search Engine</b></a>`

*Question* : But wouldnt it display : `<b>Search Engine</b>` instead of **`Search Engine`** ?

*Answer*: No. it won't  , it would have been if you html encoded the `<` and `>`.

(you could have tried it yourself ;-))

Comment: Yes. Will the hyperlink work after residing the anchor tag into bold tag?

Comment: My intention to ask a question was why it shouldn't work when I reside bold tag inside anchor tag?

Comment: The two ways of nesting have the same effect by default, but the difference matters in styling. For example, if you set `b { color: green }` in CSS, then the link text will be green in the latter case, but not in the former (since the text is in an `a` element, which obeys settings for link colors).

Answer (score 2):

this should do just fine

```
<b><a href="http://www.google.co.in">Search Engine</a></b>
```

## [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4eb2/)

Comment: i need hyperlink with text bold and uppercase.